# Disk space not free up after photos and videos are deleted from Photos app

Tags: macos, photos.app

In Photos app of my MacBook, I delete hundreds of photos. Then I go to `Show Recently Deleted` screen, click `Delete All`.

However, my disk space is same as before as shown on Finder.

How can I get the disk space back?

Comment: Did you clear the trash bin ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pictures didn't get deleted because they still exist in iPhoto or Aperture, whichever one you use.  As Apple says in [this support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204476), Photos saves disk space by creating links to the already-existing files in iPhoto/Aperture, rather than duplicating them. That means that if you want to delete a file, you need to make sure it's deleted everywhere.

If you can live without ever using iPhoto/Aperture again, go to your `Pictures` folder and delete `iPhoto Library` and `Aperture Library`. That way, the only copies of your pictures will be the ones in Photos, and deleting them will free up space on your computer.